# new kali-themes package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, dpkg

I have a problem with installing `kali-themes` package on Kali Linux. The error I get is the following:

```
eaving 'diversion of /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml to /etc/xdg/xfce4/panel/default.xml.original by kali-
themes'
dpkg-divert: error: unknown option --no-rename

Use --help for help about diverting files.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.1.0_all.deb (--unpack):
 new kali-themes package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.1.0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any thougths ?

Answer (score 4):

Solved here, that's what i did :

1. First, create a new directory and extract the `.deb` there

   ```bsh
   mkdir tmp
   dpkg-deb -R /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.1.0_all.deb tmp
   ```
2. Edit the extracted files, by looking for `"--no-rename"` and replace it with `""`.

   ```
   cd tmp/DEBIAN
   leafpad preinst
   grep "no-rename" ./* -r
   sed -i "s/--no-rename//g" <files from above grep>
   ```
3. Repack and execute the .deb

   ```
   dpkg-deb -b tmp fixed.deb
   sudo dpkg -i fixed.deb
   ```

Comment: This worked! As a side note, the *.deb can be created anywhere. The paths indicated above are only illustrative

Comment: The fixed.deb did not work out of the box. I had to install kali-themes-common. `apt-get install kali-themes-common`.

Comment: `grep "no-rename" ./* -r` gives no output. So what to put in place of <files from above grep> @muru

Comment: @PranKumarSarkar I'm not the answer author. However - is it the same package and the same error? Maybe you the previous steps didn't complete correctly? Consider posting a new question showing each command you ran and the output you got.

Comment: I encountered this blocker after updating my Kali Linux VM. to solve if I ran the commands below respectively

"sudo touch  /etc/xdg/plasma-workspace/env/kali-themes-purple.sh"

*"sudo apt --fix-broken install"*

It worked for me - I hope it works for you #cheers